# Javascript form validation, onblur validation and submitting

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, validating

I am writing a basic form validation script, basically as we go through the form each field is checked onblur like this

```
            <p>
                <label>Full Name *</label>
                <input type="text" id="fullName" value="" onblur="validate('FullName', 'fullName');" /> 
                <span class="formHint" id="hintFullName">Enter your full name</span>
                <span id="errorFullName"></span>
                <span class="success" id="successFullName"><img src="images/tick.png" /></span>
            </p>
```

This all works fine calling the function validate which I made so that you could pass it the field name and it will just check if it has been entered etc. This is all fine. Below is the validate function.

```
    function validate(field) {


    // Get the  value of the input field being submitted
    value = document.getElementById(field).value;

    // Set the error field tag in the html
    errorField = 'error' + field;

    // Set the success field
    successField = 'success' + field;

    if (value != '') {
        document.getElementById(successField).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById(errorField).style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(successField).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(errorField).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Now my question is, after validating on the fly using the onblur what is the best way for me to proceed when submitting? Do I need to write another function to manually check all of the form fields or is there a better way.

I have been thinking about it for a while but I cant seem to think the best way to check once submitted.

Sorry if any of this doesn't make sense, been confusing myself for a few hours now.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, validation!

Yep, you'll need to manually check. How "manually" will differ. It could be straight, brute manual like this:

```
function handleOnSubmit(e) {
    validate('FullName');
    validate('ZipCode');
    validate('City');

    // Loop through all error fields and see if any are present
}
```

Not very efficient, as you know...

Instead, let's write a loop that does it!

**But** before that, I'd recommend updating your `validate` function to return true/false if an error is/isn't present.

Something like:

```
if (value != '') {
    document.getElementById(successField).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(errorField).style.display = 'none';
    return true;
} else {
    document.getElementById(successField).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(errorField).style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}
```

Alright!

Now we can create a parent validator which can call your `validate` function with all the form elements.

Something like:

```
function handleOnSubmit(e) {
    // Query your elements some how
    var inputs = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('input');

    // Loop your elements
    for (i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if( validate(inputs[i].id) === false) {
            // Error occurred - we'll prevent the form submission
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle for demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ww2grozz/

The other way (if you prefer not running the validation multiple again on already validated elements) is to maintain a state of "validated" objects. You could then check against those.

Something like this:

```
var validated = {};

function validate(field) {
    // Existing logic

    if (value != '') {
        validated[field] = true;
    } else {
        validated[field] = false;
    }
}
```

Then, going back to the above parent validator:

```
function handleOnSubmit(e) {
    // Query your elements
    var inputs = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('input');

    // Loop your elements
    for (i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        var name = inputs[i].id;

        if (!validated[name]) {
            // Prevents submission
            e.preventDefault();

            // Call validate
            validate(name);
        }
    }
}
```

A second fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ww2grozz/2/

Finally, if this is going to a server...don't forget server side validation!

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you very much.

I was playing about myself still and started doing something similar to your second fiddle, I have now put that in and it works fine except I have one more question... Sorry mind has been fried a bit today. Where we loop through the tag name, not all tags are going to be required, is there  way to miss out non required fields

Comment: @TomC - Yep! The easiest way is to add a `class` with a common class name for the elements being validated! Otherwise, you could get cute and add a check in your loop to see if `onblur` is specified (and if not, continue the loop) - Here's a fiddle that uses a regex check: http://jsfiddle.net/ww2grozz/3/ - Personally, I would recommend just adding a common class and using `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Thanks very much, used the getElementsByClassName. Thanks for the help :)